# PHP Submit based on entry

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="POST">
<?php
   if (isset($_GET['name'])){
      $searchname = $_GET['name'];
   }
?>

<table>
    <tr>
            <td>name:</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type='Text' name='name' Value='<?=$searchname?>'></td>
            <td colspan='3'><input type='Submit' value='Search'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Above I have a basic variable passed in from another page via URL. This variable is passed into a text box. When I get to the page that this is on, I want to have it search automatically, instead of me pressing the submit button. How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

Via jQuery...

```
$('button.submit').click();
```

This should do the trick. You can echo this code out via php after certain validation or other php code.

Comment: I want to have it search automatically

Comment: I've changed my answer to .click(). This should trigger a click on the button automatically. Thus should search automatically

Comment: ??? _instead of me pressing the submit button_ ?? Please read the question

Comment: Yes. If you don't want a button at all. You might want to share the search code, so we can find a better solution.